# How to use git difftool with docdiff

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, difftool

How can I use `git difftool` with `docdiff`?

For some documents I like the format how `docdiff` displays the output.
`Docdiff`, however, outputs a HTML file (if we want its nicest output).
How shall I invoke `git difftool` to make it display the HTML diff results in a browser?